# web logic scripting tool (wlst) start command not working - weblogic

Tags: weblogic

Why is this 'start' command not working? I have almost half a day experience with WLST so I am not sure what is going on.

[image]

Here is a copy paste from the shell:

```
wls:/base_domain/serverConfig> start('H')
Starting server H ...Hostname verification failed: HostnameVerifier=weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSHostnameVerifier, hostname=localhost.
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in ?
  File "<iostream>", line 1262, in start
  File "<iostream>", line 552, in raiseWLSTException
WLSTException: Error occurred while performing start : Error starting the server : Error occurred while performing start : Server with name H failed to be started
Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace :
wls:/base_domain/serverConfig>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use SSL and the HostnameVerifier is kicking in, if you have different server name than the one you are specifying Weblogic will complain.

Disable HostnameVerifier previously or make sure the names you are using match with the CN of your certificate, etc.

Comment: Thank-you for the answer! :) My problem is, I tried disabling HostnameVerifier and still received the error. Also, I have no idea how to match the names. Do you have any links to help me figure this out without having to read a whole book on Weblogic? I apologize for my ignorance.